# How to use a SQL SELECT statement with Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a combobox whose value I want to use with a SQL WHERE clause. How do you **run** a SELECT statement inside VBA based on the combobox value?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you wish to use the bound column value, you can simply refer to the combo:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = " & Me.MyCombo
```

You can also refer to the column property:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE AText = '" & Me.MyCombo.Column(1) & "'"

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset     
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

strText = rs!AText
strText = rs.Fields(1)
```

In a textbox:

```
= DlookUp("AText","MyTable","ID=" & MyCombo)
```

*edited

Comment: Thanx. Won't that only create a string containing SQL statements?

Comment: Yes. Your question does not include any information on what you want to do with the where statement.

Comment: I want to actually run the SQL statement to return a value which I can pass to a textbox, something like Me!textBox = sSQL

Comment: @Remou My question is "How do you run a SELECT statement" not create a select statement only

Comment: In that case, you should probably be using DLookUp

Comment: Thanx Remou. Will check out DLookUp.

Comment: You cannot run a select statement, you can only get a recordset or such like, which means that you really need to say what you are going to do with the select statement before anyone can provide a valid answer. In this case, you need a value, but you could have wished to iterate through a recordset to perform further operations.

Answer (score 8):

Access 2007 can lose the CurrentDb: see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167173, so in the event of getting ***"Object Invalid or no longer set"*** with the examples, use:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDB
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM myTable")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to use SQL `SELECT` statement in VBA:

```
 sSQL = "SELECT Variable FROM GroupTable WHERE VariableCode = '" & Me.comboBox & "'" 
 Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
 On Error GoTo resultsetError 
 dbValue = rs!Variable
 MsgBox dbValue, vbOKOnly, "RS VALUE"
resultsetError:
 MsgBox "Error Retrieving value from database",VbOkOnly,"Database Error"
```