# How to run sql select query in vba and store result in variable?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'd like to be able to run a `Select` query in a VBA function that will return a value. The `Select` query will be expected to either return nothing or just a single value.

Something like this query:

```sql
SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

The value I'd like to be returned in VBA would be the one ID returned by the query. This would then be stored in a VBA variable for later use. Is this possible?

Comment: Assuming the Table is in a database (Access, SQL Server, etc.) and you can get to it, then yes, it is very possible.  You should search for this with google, etc., before asking here as this is very basic and introductory, and is extensively covered many places on the internet, much better than we ever could here.

Comment: You can create a RecordSet object and execute your query with OpenRecordset function.
Here is a simple example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017036/how-to-use-a-sql-select-statement-with-access-vba

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is quite possible and would look something like this:

```
variable1 number = (SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
```

This declares your variable and populates it with the value your query returns. This only works if the query returns one value though.